# JavaScript: Change onClick value of hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, onclick

I am trying to make a button/hyperlink, that is able to hide and show my navigation bar. At first it is hidden and when I click on the a-element it changes the style and is visible. But it won't hide it again on the second click.
The hyperlink will be visible if `min-width: 480` is false (only for mobiles and small browser windows).

I tried to change the `onClick` value via javascript. I will show it below.

```html
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function showNavBar() {
    document.getElementById("navigationBar").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("navigationBar").onClick = function() { hideNavBar(); };
   }
   function hideNavBar() {
    document.getElementById("navigationBar").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("navigationBar").onClick = function() { showNavBar(); };
   }
  </script>
...
  <a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showNavBar();" class="mobileShow">MenuButton</a>
  
  <nav id="navigationBar" class="main"> <!-- begin navigation bar -->
   <ul id="navigationList" class="icon-list">
    <li>
     <a href="">
      <span class="nav-icon">
       <i aria-hidden="true" id="icon-menu" class="nav-icon"></i>
      </span>
      <span>Menu</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="">
      <span class="nav-icon">
       <i aria-hidden="true" id="icon-highscore" class="nav-icon"></i>
      </span>
      <span>Highscore</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="">
      <span class="nav-icon">
       <i aria-hidden="true" id="icon-facebook" class="nav-icon"></i>
      </span>
      <span>Facebook</span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="">
      <span class="nav-icon">
       <i aria-hidden="true" id="icon-legalnotice" class="nav-icon"></i>
      </span>
      <span>Legal Notice</span>
     </a>
    </li>   
   </ul>
  </nav> <!-- end navigation bar -->
  <section class="main">
          ...
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

I also tried similar stuff with `setAttribute()` and using the href attribute to call the functions with the same result.
I don't understand why it doesn't work after the `onClick` value is changed one time. I am desperate for help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using jQuery, you could use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method :

```
function toggleNavbar() 
{
    $("#navigationBar").toggle();
}

<a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleNavbar();" class="mobileShow">MenuButton</a>
```

Each time you'll click, it will either display or hide it depending on which state it is.

---

Assuming you're not using jQuery :

```
function toggleNavbar()
{
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navigationBar");
    if (navbar.style.display == 'block' || navbar.style.display=='')
    {
        navbar.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else 
    {
        navbar.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

<a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleNavbar();" class="mobileShow">MenuButton</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used the method without jQuery, since I never used jQuery.
I just copied and pasted your code and everything works just fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 function needed

```
 <script>               
        function showHideNavBar() {
        var myStyle = document.getElementById("navigationBar").offsetLeft;

        // check if menu is hidden 
        if(myStyle < 0){   
            document.getElementById("navigationBar").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("navigationBar").style.display = "none";
       }
    }
    </script>
     <a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showHideNavBar();" class="mobileShow">MenuButton</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById("navigationBar");
    el.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (el.style.display === "block") {
            el.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            el.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be el.style.display or something similiar? Either way around it didn't work for me :/
I had to go with @tektiv 's idea